# Count files that have unique prefixes

Tags: awk

I have set of files that looks like the following. I'm looking for a good way to count all files that have unique prefixes, where "prefix" is defined by all characters before the second hyphen.

```
0406-0357-9.jpg   0591-0349-9.jpg   0603-3887-27.jpg  59762-1540-40.jpg 68180-517-6.jpg
0406-0357-90.jpg  0591-0349-90.jpg  0603-3887-28.jpg  59762-1540-41.jpg 68180-517-7.jpg
0406-0357-91.jpg  0591-0349-91.jpg  0603-3887-29.jpg  59762-1540-42.jpg 68180-517-8.jpg
0406-0357-92.jpg  0591-0349-92.jpg  0603-3887-3.jpg   59762-1540-5.jpg  68180-517-9.jpg
0406-0357-93.jpg  0591-0349-93.jpg  0603-3887-30.jpg  59762-1540-6.jpg
```

Comment: for this sample input what would the output look like?

Comment: `ls | awk '{FS="-"}; /./{  if (a[$1$2]++ == 0) print $0;}'`

Comment: @Jidder - that awk command has multiple bugs in it as well as being idiomatically wrong. The issues that jump out: no need for semi-colons, use conditions in the condition not the action space, do not concatenate the fields for the array index as it fails based on field values (`12 3` and `1 23` both concatenate to `123`), setting FS for each record is inefficient and fails for the first record (split before FS is set), no need to print $0 as that's the default, test NF for fields present not /./, no need to explicitly print at all if the condition is in the right place.

Comment: @Jidder And more generally, if you haven't even bothered to read the manual, please don't try to "help" people.

Comment: @Jidder that works! Except for one error. Write it as an answer and I'll accept. Here's the error: both 0069-4210-0.jpg and 0069-4210-10.jpg are printed.

Comment: @EdMorton Do the semicolons cause a problem ? Pretty sure they dont so that doesn't matter. Dunno what you mean the actionspace, Concatenating the field doesnt matter as all of the names are consistent.

Comment: @RosePerrone Ill try and work out why now, ill post an updated answer when i work it out:)

Comment: @RosePerrone i cant replicate your problem and i can't see any reason why that would happen :(

Comment: @Jidder there are many things you can add to a program without it failing. Semi-colons, parentheses, null strings, etc. The fact that they don't cause your code to fail are not a good reason to add them to your programs. awk script bodies have condition spaces and action spaces written as `condition { action }`. Concatenating the fields matters a lot - I already gave you an example but if helps in terms of this problem consider files named `5976-21540-40.jpg` and `59762-1540-40.jpg`. The other items are far from petty, e.g. your script would fail to split the first file name. Think about it.

Comment: @RosePerrone Jidders script MAY produce the output you expect from the specific sample input you posted, but it is riddled with problems and WILL fail given some different file names.

Comment: @EdMorton Fair enough this would solve the only problem that isn't superficial `ls | awk '{FS="-"}; /./{  if (a[$1"-"$2]++ == 0) print $0;}'`

Comment: @Jidder - no, it absolutely would not. Again - THINK about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55799/discussion-between-jidder-and-ed-morton).

Comment: Maybe this will help. Try `printf "a-b\nc-d\n" | awk '{FS="-"; print $1}'`. See a problem, now?

Comment: Oh right, yeah i used `BEGIN` in my answer, couldn't change the comment :)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
ls *.jpg | cut -d- -s -f1,2 | uniq | wc -l
```

Or if your prefixes are always 4 digits, one dash, 4 digits, you don't need cut:

```
ls *.jpg | uniq -w9 | wc -l
```

Comment: Mind you it is strongly ill-adviced to parse `ls` output http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: @Pankrates I wouldn't say it's "strongly ill-advised" in this case. The filenames seem pretty sane.

Comment: The files are not always four digits separated by one hyphen. e.g. 59762-1540-42.jpg. That's why I want to unique on all characters before the second hyphen.

Comment: @RosePerrone In that case the first pipeline I gave should work.

Comment: +1; if you want to avoid use of `ls`, try `printf '%s\n' *.jpg` (won't protect against filenames with embedded `\n` chars., but that's rarely a real-world concern).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you actually want output, either of these might be what you want:

```
ls | awk -F'-' '{c[$1"-"$2]++} END{for (p in c) print p, c[p]}'
```

or

```
ls | awk -F'-' '!seen[$1,$2]++{count++} END{print count+0}'
```

If it's something else, update your question to show the output you're looking for.

Comment: +1 It's probably a good idea to just use `awk` instead of multiple programs as I did. Hey, is it at all a good idea to quote `ls` as I did in my answer to ensure an alias isn't used? Or is it guaranteed that an alias won't be used because it's part of a pipeline? Clearly `ls` acts a little different in a pipeline since it lists each file on a separate line. But an alias to `ls -F` still appends the classification character.

Comment: If you're going to quote `ls` then why not quote every other command too? I wouldn't bother - IMHO you're more at risk from using `ls` with `.` in your PATH than your own alias tripping you up.

Comment: I realize you wouldn't bother ... who would? It's madness! But that's the problem with aliases. If `ls` is aliased to `ls -F` and you don't want the classification characters then you pretty much have to quote it if typing the command from the command line. Another possibility is to put it into a script. Just a little problem I ran into a while ago. It's made me decide that aliases should have names different from the original command.

Comment: If `cut` is aliased to `rm -rf /` you don't want that to execute either but who does that? Anyway, whatever works for you....

Comment: +1, but the usual caveat applies to the 1st snippet: enumerating [associative] array keys will not preserve the input order.

Answer (score 0):

Parses `ls` (bad, but it doesn't look like it will cause a problem with these filenames),
uses `awk` to set the field separator as `-`.
`!seen[$1,$2]++)` uses an associative array with `$1,$2` as the key and increments, then checks if the value equals 0 to ensure it is only printed once (based on `$1` and `$2`).
`print` prints on screen :)

```
ls | awk 'BEGIN{FS="-" ; printf("%-20s%-10s\n","Prefix","Count")} {seen[$1"-"$2]++} END{ for (k in seen){printf("%-20s%-10i\n",k,seen[k])}}'
```

Will now count based on prefix with headers :)

Comment: The idiomatic awk for a functionally equivalent solution would be `ls | awk -F'-' '!seen[$1,$2]++'`.

Comment: @EdMorton This isnt code golf :) Sometimes its better for code to be easily readable :)

Comment: No, it is not, but there are idioms in awk like in most languages and use of an array named `seen[]` as I showed is one of them (and not just in awk). Google `awk seen` and you will see a slew of examples. Briefer code isn't necessarily worse code as long as it's clear (i.e. concise rather than just brief) and follows well established idioms. Anyone familiar with awk would understand immediately what my script is doing, and anyone who doesn't understand it needs to learn the idiom as it comes up constantly.

Comment: I'm not saying it is worse or better, but  i just think code doesnt need to be shortened for the sake of it. Your code will also print blank lines(well a single one), although i suppose that doesn't matter when using ls. Anyway are there any more problems with my solution now ?

Comment: I agree but conciseness is a desirable attribute of software. wrt remaining issues - just the spurious semi-colon between the BEGIN block and the body. Usually people only set `FS` in the BEGIN section when they are either saving the script in a file or also setting `OFS` to the same value (e.g. `BEGIN{FS=OFS="-"}`), otherwise they set it with -F (e.g. `-F"-"`) but that's more of a style choice I suppose.

Comment: Promising, but you're not _counting_ the results, you're just printing the first filename from each group of filenames sharing the first 2 `-`-separated tokens. A quick, but non-portable fix that works with GNU `awk` and FreeBSD/OSX `awk` (where `length()` can be used with _arrays_): `ls | awk -F '-' '{seen[$1,$2]++} END { print length(seen) }'`. A portable, but less efficient solution is to simply pipe to `wc -l`. To perform counting in `awk` itself, see  @EdMorton's answer. Ed's points about learning a language's idioms are valid.